# How to add a legend to a chart in matplotlib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to add a legend to a frequency distribution plot 
[image]

This is the code I am using.

```
train_df.Medu.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.6)
plt.title("Distribution of Mother's education")
plt.legend()
```

I want to add a legend showing what 0 stands for, 1 stands for, etc. Can anyone please help me to achieve that?

Comment: That's not really a legend.  You should consider adding [text](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) to your chart

Comment: Have you tried with `plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4], ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'quaternary'])` ?

Comment: @Guillermo - Thank you. This has worked. I will  put this answer on your behalf and accept.

Comment: @BradSolomon - Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Guillermo, I tried

```
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4], ['primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary', 'quaternary'])
```

This has worked for me.